# python regular expression returns empty string

Tags: python

Given:

```
lst = ['(abc): my name is ?123']
```

I'm trying to return everything from ': ' till the end of lst[0], for that I tried a regex expression:

```
    result = re.search(r': (.*?)', lst[0]).group(1)
```

It returns an empty string.
How can this be done using regex correctly?
Expected output :

> `'my name is ?123'`

Resources used : [Regex wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/RegularExpression)

Comment: Remove the `?` from `r': (.*?)'`. It makes your regex stop after the first matching character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you made your `.*` *lazy* by placing `?` at the end.  Lazy means match as little as possible, for a valid match.  In this case, since your pattern does not have anything to match beyond the `(.*?)`, the regex engine is matching empty string.  Just use `(.*)`, the non lazy version, and it will work.

```
lst = ['(abc): my name is ?123']
result = re.search(r': (.*)', lst[0]).group(1)
print(result)
```

This prints:

```
my name is ?123
```